# FIM Synchronization service wont start - Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, fim

User Profile Service and User Profile Synchronization services in Central Administration site is started but FIM Synchorization Service is stopped. When i try to start it, gave me this error:

> windows could not start the forefront identity manager synchronization
>   service on local computer. for more >information, review the system
>   event log. If this is non-Microsoft service, contact the service
>   vendor, adn refer to service specific error code 2146234334.

Here is the event log

> BAIL: MMS(2412): sql.cpp(8490): 0x80231334 (The sql connection string
>   has unsupported values.) BAIL: MMS(2412): sql.cpp(8533): 0x80231334
>   (The sql connection string has unsupported values.) BAIL: MMS(2412):
>   server.cpp(260): 0x80231334 (The sql connection string has unsupported
>   values.) BAIL: MMS(2412): server.cpp(3860): 0x80231334 (The sql
>   connection string has unsupported values.) BAIL: MMS(2412):
>   service.cpp(1539): 0x80231334 (The sql connection string has
>   unsupported values.) ERR: MMS(2412): service.cpp(988): Error creating
>   com objects. Error code: -2145184972. This is retry number 0. BAIL:
>   MMS(2412): clrhost.cpp(283): 0x80131022 BAIL: MMS(2412):
>   scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022 BAIL: MMS(2412):
>   server.cpp(251): 0x80131022 BAIL: MMS(2412): server.cpp(3860):
>   0x80131022 BAIL: MMS(2412): service.cpp(1539): 0x80131022 ERR:
>   MMS(2412): service.cpp(988): Error creating com objects. Error code:
>   -2146234334. This is retry number 1. BAIL: MMS(2412): clrhost.cpp(283): 0x80131022 BAIL: MMS(2412):
>   scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022 BAIL: MMS(2412):
>   server.cpp(251): 0x80131022 BAIL: MMS(2412): server.cpp(3860):
>   0x80131022 BAIL: MMS(2412): service.cpp(1539): 0x80131022 ERR:
>   MMS(2412): service.cpp(988): Error creating com objects. Error code:
>   -2146234334. This is retry number 2. BAIL: MMS(2412): clrhost.cpp(283): 0x80131022 BAIL: MMS(2412):
>   scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022 BAIL: MMS(2412):
>   server.cpp(251): 0x80131022 BAIL: MMS(2412): server.cpp(3860):
>   0x80131022 BAIL: MMS(2412): service.cpp(1539): 0x80131022 ERR:
>   MMS(2412): service.cpp(988): Error creating com objects. Error code:
>   -2146234334. This is retry number 3. BAIL: MMS(2412): service.cpp(1002): 0x80131022 Forefront Identity Manager 4.0.2450.49

Comment: What account are you using to run the FIM service? Does it have permissions on Sync DB in database?

Comment: I am use Farm account and yes it has permissions to syncs DB. The account is also in local administrators group.

Comment: I guess it stopped after installing April 2015 patch. Do you have any idea this patch might have impact on FIM Sync service?

Comment: I am guessing what has happened (and it is a common problem with Sync DB) is that during the upgrade the sync db version has not been upgraded, so that's why it is failing.

Comment: Would recommend you give this a look http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx

Comment: You think with April 2015 patch there is an upgrade to SQL db also? Network guys here do the patches and not IT team. As far as i know they did not upgrade SQL dbs but i will check with them.

Comment: Let me clarify, CU's will update the version info for all sharepoint components. This information is stored on the Sharepoint specific SQL databases. So they will be updated during any patch update. Finally, after a CU update all your sharepoint databases must be on the same version for things to work. @JesusShelby below has clearly documented the steps to perform.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying that. One more question please, how do we check upgrade status of services and databases? I already checked CA-->upgrade and Migration-->Check Upgrade Status--> Succeeded with no errors and no warnings.

Comment: I checked CA-->Manage Databases Upgrade Status  and status of SyncDC is "No Action required". But Status of Profile DB and Social DB is "Database is in compatibility range and upgrade is recommended". Can you tell me how to check upgrade status of services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i did to fix the issue.

1) I deleted User Profile Application and recreated it.
2) USP gave me an error, cannot connect to USP because application pool or User Profile Service is not started.
3) I stopped and restarted User Profile Service from CA.
4) I started USP Sync Service in CA, and it got struck on Starting.
5) Did IISRESET and recycled Timer Service. 
6) Still same issue.
7) I checked Application Pool and guess what SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool is stopped.
8) I started  SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool  and did IISRESET and recycled Timer Service.
9) Started User Profile Service Sync service from CA. It started which in turn also started "FIM Sync Service".
10) Ran Incremental synchronization and it worked with no issues.

First of all, i still don't know why FIM Sync service is stopped. But i followed the above steps and resolved the issue.

Thanks @RansherSingh and @Shelby for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Any SharePoint Update (running PSCONFIG) will usually stop the sync service.  The Sync service itself requires the Farm account be a local admin the box where it is running.

In addition to the event log I would consult your upgrade log to see if there were any warning or errors present.  Check the upgrade status of both your services (on each server) and databases.  If any of them are different or showing update required than attempt to force another upgrade

```
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force
```

If that completes successfully but the database is not upgraded you can attempt the following:

```
Get-SPDataBase | ft name, id -autosize
```

Make note of the ID for your service databases that are not upgraded

```
$db = Get-SPdataBase <GUID>
$db.upgrade($true);
```

As @RansherSingh pointed out check out Spence Harbars articles - It's basicly the bible on UPS.

Last but not least - consider how complicated your setup is.  If you are using out the box UPS and don't have a lot of custom attributes or import rules, it is probably just quicker to create a new UPS.  It doesn't make sense T/S something for a couple of days if you can deploy a new one in an hour.